# How to retrieve pdf and doc files from mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to retrieve pdf and doc files that i have successfully saved in mysql db and let users have access to it.But this is what i get `userimages/1364700305.30527.pdf`. The code for retrieving the files is below:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['svreg'])) {
    $svreg = $_GET['svreg'];
    $query = "
      SELECT image_file, note_title, note_commt
      FROM notez
      WHERE svreg = '$svreg'
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    list($image_file, $note_title, $note_commt) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
?>
<a href="veh_over_view.php?svreg=<?=$svreg;?>"><?=$image_file;?></a> <br>
```

Yes i have the full path in db.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) hole in your code. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: can you explain "But this is what i get userimages/1364700305.30527.pdf." does that mean that you get an incomplete path in the image filename? do you have the full path in db

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) caused by adding unescaped `$_GET` or `$_POST` data to queries. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Comment: thank you for the advice ,i will work on it.

Comment: May help u http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain very well what you want so this is what I understand that you want

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['svreg'])) {

        $svreg = $_GET['svreg'];

        $query = "
          SELECT image_file, note_title, note_commt
          FROM notez
          WHERE svreg = '".$svreg."'
        ";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

        while(list($image_file, $note_title, $note_commt) = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

             <a href="veh_over_view.php?svreg=<?=$svreg;?>"><?=$image_file;?></a> <br> 

    <?php }

    }?>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I have a link to pdf and docx files stored in mysql db. What am try to do is retrieve the files from db, so users can view or download them. I think am not able to get the path to the folder that contain the files correctly.